# intellij tomcat configuration port numbers

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

When I configure a local tomcat server configuration in intellij, the following dialog is shown. You configure the start script and port numbers. Why does intellij require a port number if the tomcat's server.xml has port numbers specified? I know intellij reads the server config because it is picking up my certs file location.

[image]

Comment: How can you open this screen in Intellij?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application's like eclipse and Intellij starts its own instance of tomcat. If you have your installed tomcat running in port 8080 you can tell these ide's to start another instance of tomcat in some other port no.
 Hope this helps..

Comment: Makes sense but why does it ask you to choose an existing tomcat install. Is that just to get configuration?

Comment: @JeffStorey didnt get you. Could you please  explain it a bit.--- "why does it ask you to choose an existing tomcat install"----

Comment: in the screenshot above, there is an "application server" dropdown. that points to an existing tomcat installation. if it's running an embedded version, is it just using that existing installation for configuration information (such as keystore locations)

Comment: @JeffStorey In that dropdown you will be able to select other servers like Jboss.In order to create a tomcat instance we should give information about where the base dir is. To create another instance of tomcat it requires some list of configurations which are common to all tomcat instances.But if you take the case of port numbers. It should be different for different instances. Intellij is giving you an option to run that particular instance of tomcat on some other port number so that it won't affect other tomcat instances.

Answer (score 3):

In the application.properties file, Add server.port=8085(or any custom port of your choice). `server.port` property is a predefined [spring property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html).